# Perl matching characters bigger than a given length

Tags: regex, perl

I have been struggle to write regex that matches words longer than a given length within parentheses. First I thought I could do this with `\(\w{a,}\)` but I realize that it doesn't match with words with white space (ab cd ef). All I want to do is find out any characters within parentheses longer than, for instance, 3 characters. How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a word with white space?

if you want to match any character then use `.`

```
\(.{3,}\)
```

`.` matches any character except newlines

But be careful, this is greedy. it will match for example also

```
(a)123(b)
```

To avoid this you could do something like

```
\([^)]{3,}\)
```

See it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uebp)

`[^)]` means any character except a `)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a character class that includes both `\w` and `\s`:

```
\([\w\s]{a,}\)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do you mean?

```
  \([\w\s]{a,}\)
```

Comment: Ughhh didn't know I can group \w \s with [ ]. I'm still noob with perl =/

Answer (score 0):

if it has a space in it it's not a word anymore.

is matching any characters fine `\(.{a,}\)`? Or you just need the whitespace `\(\(\w|\s\){a,}\)`?